# Is it possible to change shared library references in a shared object file?

Tags: python, c, macos, shared-libraries, cpython

I have a `.so` file which contains a reference to `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python` (I can see this path hard-coded in plaintext within the .so file). I don't have access to the source that built the `.so` file.

I'd like to use a different version of the python library (stored in `/opt/local/Library`). Is it possible to edit the `.so` file to reassign this path?

Comment: For future reference, instead of `strings`-ing the file, the best way to find dependencies is `otool -L foo.so` (and `man otool` or `otool -h` to see the other useful stuff it can do for you).

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you have (at least) two Python 2.7 builds in addition to the ones that came with your system? This is almost always a recipe for trouble, even before you make things more complicated by trying to share modules between them…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be able to permanently change the reference by using `install_name_tool` included with OS X Xcode command line tools.

```
install_name_tool -change old-lib-path new-lib-path path-to.so
```

However, if `new-path` is longer than the original `old-path`, there may not be room in the field in the bundle file (.so) to do so.  The `man` page for `install_name_tool` cautions:

> For this tool to work when the install names or rpaths are larger the
>   binary should be built with the ld(1) -headerpad_max_install_names
>   option.

Also, there is no guarantee that the new Python you wish to use was built in a way that is compatible with the old shared library expected by the .so you are trying to modify.  There may be differences in universal CPU architectures, OS X deployment targets, and Python build options (for example, UCS-2 vs UCS-4) that may preclude success.  You should make a copy of the .so before attempting to modify it.

Comment: +1 for the last paragraph. MacPorts Python will probably _not_ be compatible with Apple Python, unless you get very lucky.

Comment: And +0 for the rest only because I can't +1 again. I believe at least Apple and python.org recent versions will have sufficient padding that this will work (as in "successfully change the path", not necessarily "actually load up properly and not crash"). But of course you should check for failure.

Comment: Note that the original library path is *not* to an Apple-supplied Python (that would be `/System/Library/...`), rather to another user-installed Python, possibly one from python.org.  In that case, you'd need to know which of the python.org Python 2.7's it was: one is 32-bit-only 10.3+, the other is 64-/32-bit 10.6+.

Comment: I was attempting to write generically-useful comments (I did say "Apple and python.org" in the second comment), but you're right, I screwed up the first comment; it should have said "Apple, python.org, etc. Python". And the Python in this case probably is python.org or Enthought, because those are the most common ways people who don't know what they're doing end up with a Python in /Library.

Comment: This is a nice, helpful explanation. Thank you